# Please suggest a better design/workaround for my table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an e-commerce site that would have many images in the future. Current table design for images is as follows.

```
id (Primary)    int(11)
p_id            int(11)  // product id
original        varchar(1000) // original image url
thumbnail       varchar(1000) // thumbnail image url - 76x76
medium          varchar(1000) // medium image url    - 228x228
large           varchar(1000) // large image url - 560x560
is_featured     tinyint(4)   // if featured image
```

**Table name**: pimages (allows multiple images) for a given product id.

**To do**: It has been working fine till now, but I need to add height/width of every image (original, thumbnail, medium and large) to specify their dimensions so that I can parse them into html directly for faster browser rendering.

**Catch**: The images may or may not be of the size specified. Say a medium image is of 228x50 or 200x228.

**Possible solution**: Add 4 height/width columns, one for each. But it doesn't sound too good.

Comment: first of all, what is the need to store **thumbnail** and **medium** image into the database? if it is mandatory for you then **Possible solution** is okay/.

Comment: these are urls to the images and they are named differently. Say thumbnail is example.com/abc/product-1-76x76.png and medium is example.com/abc/product-1-228x228.png

Comment: still no need to store them, what you can do is: make 3 folders with name original, medium, thumb and then store image into those folders. give same name for all the 3 images. For example, for product 1 you can save them into folder like: original/pro_1, medium/pro_1, thumb/pro_1.

Comment: What about the height/width for different images?

Comment: why do you want to store them? here no need of them

Comment: here's why https://gtmetrix.com/specify-image-dimensions.html

Comment: this is to mean that make thumb and medium thumb with one specific dimension, all thumb and medium images should have same size.

Comment: I don't necessarily think so. Also, my images aren't specifically square shaped so that I can just leave it there. all the images thumbnail, medium and large will have the same h/w-ratio as their original image and would change from product to product.

Comment: though, yes, it makes more sense to edit these images before hand and upload them in square shape.

Comment: Please give your design as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store all the 3 images in Database:

What you can do is:

- make **3 folders** with name original, medium, thumb
- store an image in those folders
- **give the same name** for all the 3 images.

**From original image**, 
make the medium size thumb with a dimension of let's say: 250*250. 
make small thumb with a dimension of let's say: 100*100

**For example,** 

for product 1 you can save them into folder like original/product-1, medium/product-1, thumb/product-1

```
To fetch the original image: example.com/original/product-1
To fetch the medium thumb image: example.com/medium/product-1
To fetch the thumb image: example.com/thumb/product-1
```

Comment: It would require me to edit my images with same width and height, but for now, I'll have it your way.

Comment: @abhig10 Sure. You should try this.

Answer (score 0):

instead i would suggest you to change your `pimages` table structure to this

```
id (Primary)    int(11)
p_id            int(11)  // product id
image        varchar(1000) // original image url
width        int(11)
height       int(11)
type         enum('original', 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large')
is_featured     tinyint(4)   // if featured image
```

so it mean your will store all images one by one, and will sore as match attributes as you need for each separated image (width, height, ...), and will separate them by type by `type enum('original', 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large')` filed where you will mention that this one is your 'large' image

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions:

- You have one multiple images for each product
- each image is available in at least one size
- the URL for each image size will be different
- you cannot use a naming convention to derive the URL for each image
- you feature an image, not the size of the image (e.g. "front picture", not "front picture - thumbnail")
- you store the original image somewhere, and have a process for resizing it.

I'm also assuming that in the future, you'll want more than 4 sizes (large is not so large on retina displays, for instance).

In that case, I'd have:

```
Table PRODUCTS
----------------
p_id (primary key)
.....

Table PRODUCT_IMAGES
---------------------
image_id (pk)
p_id (fk)
original_url
original_height
original_width
is_featured

table IMAGE_SIZES
----------------- 
image_id (fk)
type         enum('original', 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large')
height
width
```

Comment: Your answer is good but I wouldn't want to have an extra table `image_sizes`. so for now, I'll just manage with what I have.